# Worst technical knowledge gap you've seen?

Tags: language-agnostic

What's the worst technical misunderstanding you've ever seen?  Worst abuse of a good system due to lack of knowledge?

Answer (score 9):

## I didn't know I could write my own functions (php)

When I was teaching myself to program years ago I wrote an entire php web application **without a single function**.  All code reuse was done by calling include(...) on other .php scripts.  The book I was learning from never introduced the concept of user defined functions.  (The day I learned about functions was a very good day.)

Comment: holy crap! are you serious :D

Comment: Seen a similar thing before at a job I consulted on very briefly (bought in by the product owners - but had to work with a different company that developed the web app). 
This dev company had the mistaken belief that calling a function was too expensive in PHP so their code tended to look like what you're saying. 
While there were a couple of method calls and includes, a regex to validate an email address in a couple of places shouldn't be encaplusate in a method - but copy paste it wherever you need it - eventually gave up trying to convince them that method call overhead is not important

Comment: The app i currently have to maintain must have been from you. Ok, it has a wrapper around the mysql functions but thats it. I've seen a single SQL Query repeated 12 times in _one_ file.

Comment: Don't worry... my code has long since died and been replaced.  I've learned my lessons! (and I worked alone at the time and had no one to teach me better practices) :)

Comment: well you should consider yourself successful. I don't think it is easy to achieve that :)

Answer (score 5):

**Polymorphism**.

Didn't really understand it's power at first. Resulted into bloated, and over complicated routines. Boy, try not to remember those days...

Comment: I can see what you mean. At first I was mostly seeing Object Orientation as way to keep functions and data together. Like how C++ let you declare functions inside a struct. I was aware of the virtual keyword but I didn't really see the usefulness. Smalltalk implementation of the if control structure with polymorphic #ifTrue: and #ifFalse was a real eye-opener.

Answer (score 2):

The worst i've ever done was storing comma seperated ids in a database. I did not fully understand joins so it was the easiest thing i could do but the queries where horrible
(WHERE foo_ids LIKE "%,$id,%" OR foo_ids LIKE "$id,%" OR foo_ids LIKE "%,$id").

The worst thing i regularly see are classes that just work like namespaces with all methods public static (PHP).

EDIT:
I just remembered the time when a school mate tried to create an XML file for a database table

Table:

```
teacher_id | name
         1 | foo
         2 | bar
  ...      |   ...
```

His XML:

```
<teachers>
  <id1>foo</id1>
  <id2>bar</id2>
   ....
</teachers>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Database joins in PHP code

When teaching myself SQL with PHP, I was using SQL like a permanent flat-file type store with complex filtering capabilities (WHERE).  I did not understand that you could "join" tables together.  All join operations were implemented in a PHP function after all the data was pulled into memory.  If I knew more back then I might have called it a nested loops join function!  (That will teach you to de-normalize your data very fast!)

<sub>I'm sorry database gods!</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Some Java - "developer" (lol) trying to write a piece of software in C#, not knowing that this is a modern language with a "foreach" - statement.

Result:

Software had iterations using... iterators. Ugly, 90s style, typical of Java.

Made me hate Java even more. :-(

Comment: But Java has a foreach statement (`for (e : iterator) {}`), so the developer was just generally ignorant.

Comment: Except theres a time and place for iterators depending on the operations being performed in the loop. The big example is when you need to remove something from the collection that you're iterating over.

Comment: @Freiheit

If you are doing that THIS way, you are doing it wrong. IEnumerables are to be considered immutable, if you need to mutate them, you are supposed to create a modified copy. Everything else is premature optimization.

Comment: Slight correction to my previous comment: that shouldn't be "iterator" but "collection"/"object being iterated over".

Comment: @Turing complete - not in Java: right from the early days, it's explicitly supported non-immutable Enumerators. I consider this an intelligent improvement on early C based enumeration that was more interested in what was easy to implement than in what real-world programs actually needed.

Comment: @Adam

If a program needs a mutable enumeration, the developer isn't a good one. Functional programming will tell you why. :-)

Answer (score 1):

A colleage and I worked as consultants on a medium software project. He'd been working for a year on similar projects, so he was billed to the client as an "expert" on the platform.

Soon I discovered that my colleage didn't fully understood the fine points of file I/O on the language we were using, consequently leaving lots of subtle bugs. The funny thing is, all his previous projects had the same subtle bugs but the clients learned to use the system in ways that didn't trigger them.

Answer (score 1):

Back when I was a beginner, I wrote some code in PHP without understanding pointers, objects, or even tuples/structs.  I just built all my data structures using PHP's ridiculously flexible, dynamically typed arrays.  It's actually pretty surprising how much you can accomplish that way, but I feel bad for anyone (including myself a few months later) that ever needed to modify that code.

Answer (score 0):

That I had to call `ToString()` on every variable when concatenating strings, even if the variables were strings.

**Examples**:

```
Enum.GetName(...).ToString()
myDate.ToShortDateString().ToString()
```

...